# Selecionar localização Google Maps, similar uber/99

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, react-native

Fala gente, tudo bom?

Estou fazendo um app onde preciso selecionar o local onde o usuário está, muito similar ao uber e ao 99. Entretanto não quero confiar apenas na geolocation, queria setar diretamente no maps. Sei que posso fazer com Marker e click, mas do modo em questão,veja imagens, deixa um melhor UX. Estou tendo problema para entender como a tela é feita. Sugestões?

Minhas conclusões atuais: Aparentemente, o ícone é um ponto flutuante separado do Mapa. O ponto de orientação do mapa é orientado para mesma posição do ícone ta tela. Quando você da zoom no mapa, ele direciona para o mesmo ponto de orientação. Não consegui resolver o problema do zoom ainda.

Muito obrigado desde já

[image: Exite na tela um ponto flutuante, aparentemente, não associado ao mapa. Ao navegar pelo mapa, o ícone se mantém no mesmo lugar na tela do celular. Ao dar zoom em quarquer parte da tela, o mapa é direcionado a posição do ícone. Ao parar de se mover, a aplicação percebe os dados da geolocalização]

Comment: E qual é o problema do zoom?

Comment: O zoom, por padrão, é focado no ponto do mapa que você está focando. No uber/99, o zoom, não importa onde fizer no mapa, é direcionado para o ponto do centro.